# Help with algebraic simplification

Tags: linear-algebra

As part of a solution to a proof by induction question I've been working on there is this re-arranging/simplification:

$$
\frac{1-(1-a)^{n+1}+a(1-a)^{n+1}}{a} = \frac{1-(1-a)(1-a)^{n+1}}{a} = \frac{1-(1-a)^{n+2}}{a}
$$

I'm having difficulty understanding what was done with the **a** before (1-a) in
$
a(1-a)^{n+1}
$. Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? Where does $-(1-a)^{n +1} + a(1-a)^{n+1}$ become $(1-a)(1-a)^{n+1}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k = (1-a)^{n+1}$ then,

$$
\frac{1-k+ak}{a} = \frac{1+k(-1+a)}{a} = \frac{1-k(1-a)}{a} = \frac{1-(1-a)(1-a)^{n+1}}{a} = \frac{1-(1-a)^{n+2}}{a}
$$

Comment: Perfect - I found this a really useful way of looking at it. Many thanks.

Comment: @high-confessor if it helped you then do upvote and accept the answer :)